# Como colocar um valor que está salvo no banco de dados em uma combobox?

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, winforms, combobox

Estou usando C# Windows Forms com .NET 3.5.

Inseri todos os estados da federação dentro da propriedade itens da minha *combobox*. Quando eu busco um registro salvo do meu BD, a *combobox* não assume o valor.

Por exemplo: quando busco um registro que contenha "AC" na tabela do banco, a *combobox* não assume o valor, ela fica em branco.

O código:

```
Conta conta = new Conta();
conta = controle.Ler(id);            

cboEstado.SelectedItem = conta.estado;
```

Comment: Você poderia detalhar mais o seu problema? Como está esse pedaço de código, por exemplo. Isso facilitaria prover uma resposta que o ajudasse.

Comment: Editei o post, obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da pra ser mais simples. Com base no seu Exemplo:

```
Conta conta = new Conta();
conta = controle.Ler(id); 
cboEstado.DataSource = conta;
cboEstado.ValueMember = "ID ou IDENTIFICADOR UNICO DO REGISTRO";
cboEstado.DisplayMember = "SIGLA (acho que deve ser estado o nome da sua coluna)";
cboEstado.SelectedItem = conta.estado;
cboEstado.Refresh();
```

Comment: Foi só colar o cboEstado.Refresh() que funcionou. Valeu!

Comment: Em Windows forms é necessario recarregar os componentes. No ambiente web o DataBind(); faz esse trabalho dando um postback, mas muita gente esquece.

Answer (score 4):

Você precisa atribuir o **DataSource** no seu **Combobox**, a classe "Estados" possui os atributos **"Id"** e **"Sigla"**

```
public class Estados
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Sigla { get; set; }

    public Estados(int id, string sigla)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Sigla = sigla;
    }
}
```

No Form Load, fazemos a chamada:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Estados> estados = new List<Estados>(); /* Criei uma lista do tipo Estados */
    estados.Add(new Estados(1, "SP")); /*  Carregando minha lista com dados */
    estados.Add(new Estados(2, "RJ"));
    estados.Add(new Estados(3, "BA"));


    comboBox1.DataSource = estados; /* Atribuo o DataSource a minha lista */
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id"; /* O valor do combox eu pego do "Id" da minha classe Estados */
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Sigla"; /* O valor que o usuário irá ver no Combox */

    comboBox1.SelectedValue = 2 /* Selecionei o registro 2 que é igual a "RJ" */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seguinte, se você carregar na lista de `Items`, objetos do tipo A, somente poderá usar na propriedade `SelectedItem` objetos que se comparem com este tipo.

O seguinte exemplo não funciona por causa disso:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    class MyClass
    {
        private string p;
        public MyClass(string p) { this.p = p; }
        public override string ToString() { return this.p; }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new[]
            {
                new MyClass("RJ"),
                new MyClass("MG"),
                new MyClass("SP"),
            });

        this.comboBox1.SelectedItem = "SP"; // tipo string não se compara com tipo MyClass
    }
}
```

Por outro lado, se eu inserir strings na lista de itens, ai sim, eu posso usar a propriedade SelectedItem com uma string, pois duas strings se comparam entre si:

```
        this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new[]
            {
                "RJ",
                "MG",
                "SP",
            });

        this.comboBox1.SelectedItem = "SP";
```