# Combobox em Banco de Dados

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Sempre utilizei Delphi e lá tinha com componente chamado `DBLookupcombobox` onde era possível listar os dados de uma *tabela* e usar o campo *ID* desta referida salvando na tabela principal, por exemplo:

Em um cadastro de Funcionários tenho o `ID_Cidade` que é *FK* da tabela `Cidade`, com o `DBLookupcombobox` eu mostrava o nome da cidade e nas propriedades do componente eu conseguia salvar o `ID_cidade` na tabela `Funcionário`, o Combobox faz isso no C#?

Configurando ele pelo *properties*?

Comment: Faz sim. De uma olhada nessa [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3419/como-colocar-um-valor-que-est%C3%A1-salvo-no-banco-de-dados-em-uma-combobox).

Answer (score 2):

No evento Load:

```
cboClientes.DataSource = null;
cboClientes.ValueMember = "id";
cboClientes.DisplayMember = "Nome";
cboClientes.DataSource = _dt;
if (cboClientes.DataSource != null)
{
    cboClientes.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
cboClientes.Refresh();
```

É só configurar os eventos:

```
private void cboClientes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cboClientes.SelectedValue = idCliente;
}

private void cboClientes_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    idCliente = (int)cboClientes.SelectedValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Juliano, fiz um exemplo bem simples usando o `EntityFramework` como fonte de dados para o combo box, o código completo você pode ver [aqui](https://github.com/pablotdv/StackOverflow/tree/master/ComboBoxDB)

Aproveitei também para criar um exemplo no ASP.NET MVC, que você pode ver [aqui](https://github.com/pablotdv/StackOverflow/tree/master/ComboBoxDBASPNetMVC)

Popular o ComboBox

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (ComboBoxDBContext context = new ComboBoxDBContext())
    {
        comboBox1.DataSource = context.ProdutoGrupos.ToList();
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "ProdutoGrupoId";
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Descricao";
        comboBox1.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Recuperar o Valor selecionado

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (ComboBoxDBContext context = new ComboBoxDBContext())
    {
        Produto produto = new Produto();
        produto.ProdutoGrupoId = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue);
        produto.Descricao = textBox1.Text;
        context.Produtos.Add(produto);
        context.SaveChanges();
     }
}
```

Por experiência de também ser um programador que saiu do Delphi, lhe digo para abstrair um pouco a questão de configuração por propriedades. Não que isso não seja possível, mas todas as vezes que tentei trabalhar no Windows Forms ligando propriedades, fiquei um pouco frustrado.

Answer (score 1):

Um jeito simples, e utilizo isso no software que fiz foi o seguinte (vou utilizar como exemplo uma lista dos estados brasileiros, mas pode ser os dados retornados do banco de dados):

1. Li os valores de uma outra lista/fonte de dados e passei para o combobox da seguinte forma:

   ```
   combo.DataSource = new BindingSource(new Dictionary<string, string>()
   {
       { "AC", "AC" },
       { "AL", "AL" },
       { "AP", "AP" },
       { "AM", "AM" },
       { "BA", "BA" },
       { "CE", "CE" },
       { "DF", "DF" },
       { "ES", "ES" },
       { "GO", "GO" },
       { "MA", "MA" },
       { "MT", "MT" },
       { "MS", "MS" },
       { "MG", "MG" },
       { "PA", "PA" },
       { "PB", "PB" },
       { "PR", "PR" },
       { "PE", "PE" },
       { "PI", "PI" },
       { "RJ", "RJ" },
       { "RN", "RN" },
       { "RS", "RS" },
       { "RO", "RO" },
       { "RR", "RR" },
       { "SC", "SC" },
       { "SP", "SP" },
       { "SE", "SE" },
       { "TO", "TO" }
   }, null);

   combo.DisplayMember = "Value";
   combo.ValueMember = "Key";
   ```

Value do Combobox, você aponta ela para o BindingSource da tabela que você quer salvar a propriedade vinculada no ValueMember.